# Xamarin Forms - Implementing Singleton

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, singleton

I am actually trying to archive global variables in Xamarin where any page can consume it. After a lot of research, looks like the best way to archive such thing is using the Singleton design pattern. I am facing difficulty to implement this. take a look...

global.cs

```cs
using System;

namespace xamarin_forms
{
    sealed class Global
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
        private static Global _instance = null;  

        private Global() 
        { 
        }

        static internal Global Instance() 
        {   
            if (_instance == null) 
            {  
                _instance = new Global();  
            }  

            return _instance;  
        }  
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xamarin_forms
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        Global global = Global.Instance();
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new PageWelcome();
            global.test = "123";
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {


        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so far, I just created my singleton class with a simple test property. I set this to 123 when I initialize my application.

Now, on another page, welcome page...I'd like to read the value that I set previously on the initialization...

PageWelcome.xaml.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace xamarin_forms
{
    public partial class PageWelcome : ContentPage
    {
        public PageWelcome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Global global = Global.Instance();
            DisplayAlert("Alert", global.test, "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Actually this is not working. It's returns me a null. So, how to use this correctly ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App's constructor, you first create an instance of `PageWelcome`. This instance reads the `test` property of your `Global` singleton and displays its contents in an alert. At this point, no value has been assigned to that property as far as I can see.

It is only after the `PageWelcome` constructor finishes that you actually assign a value to the `test` property of your singleton. Change your App constructor to

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    global.test = "123";
    MainPage = new PageWelcome();
}
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: Oh, boy ! yes ! you are right. A stupid detail: The order really matters ! tyvm !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Singleton. 
Just create a static class with your variables static and you would be able to use them on any Page, like you want global variables.

Comment: hey Micael ! Well...I read a lot of things already about it. Everyone had an opinion about the best practice. I am not telling that mine is better than yours, but since we have a plenty of options, I will need to figure out the best on my own ! But I promise to study about static classes . ty !

Comment: all you have to do this     public static string test { get; set; }. Boom, magic

Comment: Do not use static classes, because of negative impact within testing and no possibility of decoupling!

Answer (score 1):

```
// 1. Create static class Global with string _Test
public static class Global
{
    public static void Init()
    {
        // your init class
    }

    private static string _Test { get; set; }
    public static string Test
    {
        get => return _Test;
        set => _Test = value;
    }
}

// 2. Init Global in your App.cs
public App()
{
    Global.Init();
}
// 3. Then use them on any page
public PageWelcome()
{
    Global.Test = "123";
}
```